# Using an existing definition in Isabelle/ Hol

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

I'm new Isabelle/Hol user and I have some confusion regarding using the existing definitions in Isabelle. I have to define a Complete lattice structure  and Complete Partial Order (CPO) structure  in my model. I found that those defintion already exists as Classes in the HOLCF Porder.Thy and Lattice.thy. So If I wanted to include those definitions in my model  how should I proceed ? Like I copy paste all the definition or there is a specific command for that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the header of your own theory, you can *import* other theories. Complete lattices already exist in the `Main` theory (which you would usually import anyway if you're using HOL). Other theories can be referenced using `~~/src/HOL/...` (Isabelle automatically substitutes `~~` for the home path of your Isabelle installation).

For the precise syntax, I recommend reading through [prog-prove](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2016/doc/prog-prove.pdf), especially §2.1.

Comment: thank you larsh for your answer, I already ported the theoreies of Complete Latices and Complete Partial Order , How ever my confusion is how to initiate them in my model , I get confused between the local and class  styles , so I was looking for a simple explicit example to show how it is done for now I just defined another calss  cpo_T to represent a cpo structure called T + a definition about  function continuity but I am not sure if this is how it should be done  
class  cpo_T = cpo +
assumes c: "chain C ⟹ (⨆i. f (C i)) = f (⨆i. C i)"
begin
 end   the pdf doesn't answer my question